# Self-sizing Table View Cells in Ios UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to self adjust the *uItableview* Cell element.

> automatic adjust of **UITableViewCell** size.

Comment: automatic adjust of UITableViewCell size... ? is not clear , it means height based on content or else ...?

Comment: Hi Dhanaraj .. please provide the extra information regarding the question.

Comment: use this one : http://useyourloaf.com/blog/self-sizing-table-view-cells/

Answer (score 1):

So, there are two lines of code to make your cellHeight self sizing.

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140 // set your estimatedHeight
```

But, be sure that your constraints in cell are installed right, and views have an intrinsic content size.

See this tutorial for more information
https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells